# M5 Lora module and Nano - does not receive / transmit

Tags: lora

I'm working on my first Arduino project using LoraWAN8688 ASR6501 M5 module. I would like one nano to send message, and another nano to receive and read it.

I believe they are not sending or receiving data. I can see Transmission led flashing on one of them, but not Receive led on another.

I think, that my Lora module must be configured before it will be used to send and receive data from Arduino.

How can I send AT+ commands to the LORA module to configure it? Do I need any additional cables or connectors, or can I use Arduino to set it up?

Can I use Serial.println("AT+ADDRESS=1"); to set address via andruino?

[image: my setup for tests]

RECEIVER CODE:

```
String incomingString;

void setup() {
// put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("AT+ADDRESS=3");
}

void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
if(Serial.available()){
incomingString = Serial.readString();
if (incomingString.indexOf("TeamA") >0){
delay(500);
}
}
}
```

TRANSMITTER CODE:

```
unsigned long lastTransmission;
const int interval = 1000;

void setup() {
// put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("AT+ADDRESS=2");
}

void loop()
{
if (millis() > lastTransmission + interval) {
Serial.println("AT+SEND=1,6,TeamA");
delay(2000);
lastTransmission = millis();
}
}
```

Comment: the 9 V battey consists of four AAAA cells ... it is questionable that it has the capacity to power your project